# NSXMLParser RSS Load More

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, xml-parsing, rss, nsxmlparser

I am able to successfully parse the items (title, link, description, creator, pubDate and Cdata image) from RSS feed. Here is where I am stuck. I want to implement "Load More" option so that when a user scrolls down the tableview, he will either click on a button to or just scroll more to reveal more tableview cells.

What I want is the parser to parse 10 items at a time and on clicking load more, it should parse and load 10 more items.

Last, is there any way I can format the RSS feed to show 10 items on first page and 10 on next and so on.

Comment: Is it your own RSS feed or some other's feed?

Comment: Yes its my own RSS feed.

Comment: RSS may be the wrong tool for this.  Typically, an RSS feed displays the last X entries, with no concept of "Load more" or "Show all entries".  It's up to the client RSS reader to periodically check the feed, determine which entries are new, and save them to a local database.  While there have been proposals for a standard way to paginate feeds (see http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5005#section-3), I'm not sure of the adoption rate.  What software are you using to generate the RSS feed?

Comment: Its FeedBurner. More precisely, its linked with a WordPress site.

Comment: @iccir what would you suggest instead of RSS for "Load more" functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create RSS feed like below.

```
http://www.example.com/rssfeed.php?page=1
http://www.example.com/rssfeed.php?page=2
http://www.example.com/rssfeed.php?page=3
```

so that you can send page as parameter and can get results based on page number, send only 10 items per page.

Comment: Let me know if there is any such option in FeedBurner.

Comment: I do not know about Feedburner. But please check http://www.ehow.com/info_12189370_feedburner-entry-limits.html

Comment: Its for Blogger blog only. /feeds/posts/default?max-results=4 does not work with Wordpress etc.